# Can I upgrade to windows 10 pro?

Tags: windows, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

I have a genuine windows 8.1 laptop. One of my friend downloaded and made a windows pro pen drive and installed it. Can I install windows 10 pro using the same USB and stay genuine or Do I have to download windows home ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have the chance to upgrade to 10 via windows update if you registered/register to get the upgrade. It will downloaditself and after it's complete you will be able to upgrade your 8.1 pro to 10 pro.

Copied this:

> "By default, Windows 10 builds are pre-keyed, meaning, you do not have
>   to enter a product key and should not be prompted to enter one even
>   after Windows 10 has completed setup if you upgraded from a activated
>   Windows 7 or Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 license."

from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-activate-the-latest-windows-10-build/33f31475-93b3-4d1c-812f-4b21fbd807a7)

Other parts of the article say, once you have upgraded to 10 (from 7, 8, 8.1) and activated it you can reinstall competely.

> Can I perform a clean install using the Free upgrade? No, it will
>   require that you are running a previous qualifying version and start
>   the upgrade from within the qualifying version. You can initiate a
>   clean install after completing the Upgrade.

Which to which:
[image]

Comment: I cant upgrade via windows update because my internet is very slow, So can I upgrade from windows 8.1 home to win 10 pro without any problems via usb?

Comment: I'm not sure about the cdkey you have (if you have) for your 8.1 will work on 10. :/

Edited my answer

Comment: So what do  you suggest.. should I install or not?

Comment: It say's you shouldn't until you upgraded once from your computer. Because you won't have cd key.

Comment: What should I upgrade to , windows 10 home or pro? As my windows 8.1 is genuine I do have a CD key..right?

Comment: If you have 8.1 Pro then it wil upgrade itself to Pro when the time comes. 

Edited my answer, added a picture see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26422/discussion-between-bharat-and-shapperd).