# What do I need to upgrade Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10

I am ordering a computer that is shipped with Windows 8.1.

I used to also order the Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro Pack to upgrade to Pro.

Microsoft have discontinued the Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro Pack and I do not see such alternative item as Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Pack to upgrade a Windows 8.1 computer to Windows 10 Pro.

What do I need to also order to be able to update this Windows 8.1 computer to Windows 10 Pro when it arrives, or has the 'Pro' part (being able to join a domain etc.) been discontinued and all normal Windows 10 computers are now able to do this?

Comment: Which version does Windows 10 Upgrade Tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade) offer you?

Comment: I don't have the computer yet. I am purchasing a Windows 8.1 Home computer and I want to upgrade it to Windows 10 Pro. What do I need to buy to get the 'Pro' part?

Comment: You can check this answer : http://superuser.com/a/947408/515171 for information about Windows 10 versions. From what i can tell upgrading your Win 8 Home to Win 8 Pro should make you eligible to receive Win 10 Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pro part is still important regarding your upgrade, yes (see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/upgrade-to-windows-10-faq))

[image]

There is a Microsoft Knowledge Base article supporting your suspicions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3107057)

> As of October 30, 2015, the Windows 8 and 8.1 Pro Pack (which upgraded
>   Windows 8 Home or 8.1 Home to Windows 8 Pro or 8.1 Pro, with Media
>   Center) and Media Pack (which added Media Center to Windows 8 Pro or
>   8.1 Pro) are no longer available for purchase from Microsoft. Previously purchased feature pack licenses will still work, and valid
>   feature packs may still be available for purchase from third-party
>   retailers. Support for these products is still available.

---

You could see if a third party retailer still have stocks of this and upgrade to 8.1 Pro *before* installing Windows 10.

Alternatively, you can upgrade to Pro once Windows 10 Home is installed through the Windows Store. [This article](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-easily-upgrade-windows-10-home-windows-10-pro) covers how to do so:

> If you want the additional features, here's how to upgrade directly in
>   Windows 10…
>
> 1. Open up **All Settings** and tap or click the **Update & Security** component.
> 2. In **Update & Security**, drop down to the **Activation** section on the left
>      and tap or click the "**Go to Store**" option.
> 3. You'll be whisked straight away to the Windows Store app and land
>      directly on the page that provides quick access to purchasing the
>      Windows 10 Pro Pack.

---

This image shows what you gain from Pro over Home:

[image]